# Wanted, dead or alive: Have you seen this curve? (circular variant of cardioid)

Tags: ho.history-overview, curves-and-surfaces, geometric-constructions

Let me start with the context.  This is definitely *not* a "research level" question, but I'm hoping that the research community will be able to settle for me whether or not a particular construction has been done before or not.  I'm also hoping that the wider context will mean that this question doesn't get closed instantaneously.

I do an extension class with 10/11 year olds, not selected for their interest in mathematics (ie it's just a regular class).  One of the activities I get them to do is to draw a cardioid by joining points on a circle with straight lines.  One pair decided that instead of using straight lines, they would use curves instead.  The resulting picture is similar to a cardioid, but is not the same.

My goal is to be able to say to them one of two things:

Either:

> "Well done!  You took the construction and *played* with it, seeing what else you could make.  That's exactly what mathematicians do.  What you've discovered is called the *hyperlogical antiometric cardiobloid* and it was first made in 1832 by de Grundie.  It's linked to *hyperlogical geometry* which is a really key area of mathematics."

Or:

> "Well done!  You took the construction and *played* with it, seeing what else you could make.  That's exactly what mathematicians do.  What you've discovered is quite probably completely new!  No-one I've asked has heard of it.  That's brilliant!  What would you like to call it?"

But to say either one, I need to know if this has been seen before.  Note that it doesn't matter what the answer is, and also please note that I'm not claiming that the curve itself has any intrinsic value.  Its value is purely extrinsic in that I can use it to show the students what being a real mathematician is like.

Without further waffle, here's a more precise construction.

On a circle, draw an arc between $\theta$ and $2 \theta$ so that the arc meets the circle at right-angles (in the manner of the Poincaré disc model of hyperbolic geometry - indeed, if this has been seen before then "curve stitching in hyperbolic space" seems a likely candidate).  This draws out an envelope, just as the straight-line version draws a cardioid.  In actual fact, one can draw the full circles - not just the arcs - and get another part of the curve outside the original circle.

Using the theory of envelopes, and sticking stuff into Sagemath, I found an equation of the curve:

$$
\begin{align}
x^8 + y^8 &+ 16x^7 + 4(x^2 + 4x + 19)y^6 + 76x^6 + 48x^5 \\
&+ 6(x^4 + 8x^3 + 38x^2 + 8x - 47)y^4 - 282x^4 + 48x^3\\
&+ 4(x^6 + 12x^5 + 57x^4 + 24x^3 - 141x^2 + 12x + 19)y^2 + 76x^2 + 16x + 1 = 0
\end{align}
$$

Using Geogebra, I drew a diagram showing the curve and its construction:

[image: Hyper cardioid]

Any pointers will be gratefully received, (but please note that I no longer have access to paywalled articles (nor to MathSciNet) so if you supply references please try to find accessible ones).

Comment: PS I did ask this on Maths-SE and on G+ a week ago but to no avail.  I thought it best to write more context for MO than for MSE rather than just ask for the question to be migrated.

Comment: Please give the MSE link and also write a link to this MO question on the MathSE question.

Comment: Here's the MSE link: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1618523/2907 (and I've linked in the other direction too)

Comment: Oh, and here's a link to the geogebra worksheet that made that picture: http://ggbtu.be/m2473555

Comment: While you are most likely to get an informed answer here, if you don't, try matheducators.stackexchange next week.  Even if they don't have a pointer to the geometry literature, something in education of geometry might appear.  Gerhard "Cast Net Far And Wide" Paseman, 2016.01.24

Comment: You should try to compute a polar equation for the curve, this will make it easier to look up. Try to find it in [this site](http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/courbes2d.shtml), which seems to list an unreasonable number of historical curves and constructions thereof, and, if you can't, try contacting its author.

Comment: Not really relevant but I feel compelled to share this:  When my daughter was the same age as your students, I found her staring at a piece of paper on which she'd drawn many copies of the same right triangle in a variety of configurations.  I asked what she was doing, and she said she was trying to figure out how many different ways there are to compute the area of the same triangle --- she had fit two together to make a rectangle, four together to make a different rectangle, etc.   (CONTINUED)

Comment: (CONTINUED)  She even said something about trying to figure out what it means for two computations to be essentially different.  When I praised her exactly as you propose to praise your students ("Wow!  That's exactly the kind of question a real mathematician might ask!"), she said:  "Really?  A real mathematician might ask a question like this".  I said yes.  And she said --- this is verbatim, because I wrote it down instantly:  "Wow!  What a soul-deadening job THAT must be."

Comment: If you say the straight-line version draws a cardioid, then the curve you describe, or at least the "inside" half of it, should be the transform of the cardioid under the transformation that takes the Beltrami-Klein model of projective space to the Poincaré disk model (because the points on the unit circle are preserved by this transformation, which then maps the line segment to the circle arc, and tangency will be preserved). Maybe there is no better description.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I'll try the polar form, thanks for the suggestion.  In the meantime, your second comment was absolutely correct.  The outer half is then the inversion in the unit circle of the inner half.  I think you should post that as an answer since although it doesn't answer the "has this been seen before" part, it's a very useful point of view on the curve and not one I'd've thought of (I know of the Poincaré disc model but hadn't heard of the Beltrami-Klein one, and the passage between the two is lovely and geometric).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the original poster's suggestion, here is a slightly expanded version of what I posted as a comment:

If we consider the envelope of the family of lines $L_\theta$ which connect the points with arguments $\theta$ and $2\theta$ on the unit circle, we get a cardioid, as explained in the question.  (This fact is, for example, mentioned on [this page](http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/cardioid/cardioid.shtml) where it is attributed to Cremona.)

Now consider the map $\psi$ from the closed unit disk to itself which takes the [Beltrami-Klein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami%E2%80%93Klein_model) model of the hyperbolic plane to the [Poincaré disk model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) of the same (i.e., which takes a point $P$ of the disk to the Poincaré disk projection of the point of the hyperbolic plane whose Beltrami-Klein projection is $P$): in polar coordinates, this keeps $\theta$ unchanged and takes $r$ to $r/(1+\sqrt{1-r^2}) = (1-\sqrt{1-r^2})/r$, and it can be described geometrically in various ways.

The key facts we need are that (1) $\psi$ is a diffeomorphism on the open unit disk, a homeomorphism on the closed unit disk, and is the identity on the unit circle (i.e., ideal points of the hyperbolic plane are mapped in the same way by the Beltrami-Klein and Poincaré disk models), and (2) lines of the hyperbolic plane become line segments in the Beltrami-Klein model whereas in the Poincaré disk model they become arcs of circle perpendicular to the unit circle ("circle at infinity") at the two points where they cross it.

In particular, $\psi$ maps the segment of $L_\theta$ inside the disk to the arc of the circle $C_\theta$ that crosses the unit circle perpendicularly at the arguments $\theta$ and $2\theta$.  Since we consider the envelope of the $C_\theta$ and since $\psi$ preserves tangency in the open disk, the inner part of the curve is the image under $\psi$ of the cardioid parametrized as above.  As for the outer part, it can be described as the inversion by the unit circle of the inner part (since inversion preserves the circles $C_\theta$).

(This also suggests that maybe the nicest curve to consider is the hyperbolic one — an envelope of a family of hyperbolic lines — whose Beltrami-Klein projection is the cardioid and whose Poincaré disk projection is the one which the question was about.)

**Bonus:** Since I think the Beltrami-Klein model of the hyperbolic plane (and its analogy with the [gnomonic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection) of the sphere) deserves to be better known, I can't resist adding a couple of shameless self-plugs here for which I hope I will be forgiven: [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHvAqDuWG2M) shows a number of azimuthal projections of the spheres and their analogous projections of the hyperbolic plane, and [this JavaScript game](http://www.madore.org/~david/math/hyperbolic-maze-2.html) is a maze-without-walls in a (compact quotient of) the hyperbolic plane which can be drawn in the Beltrami-Klein or Poincaré disk projections.